# Ant building - Need to delete older version and keep new version of file(s) on build

Tags: svn, ant

I have what are called transform files that are being versioned.

Transform_Map_v01.java
Transform__Map_v02.java

I am trying to have older versions SVN deleted and new transforms added to SVN as part of the overall build process.

Any idea what I can add to my build or shared build file to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My workaround within the build file

```
    <!-- SVN Delete old Transform files -->
    <exec executable="svn">
        <arg value="delete" />
        <arg value="--force" />
        <arg value="-q" />
        <arg value="${dir}/Transform*.java" />
    </exec>
```

Generate the new files with updated filenames then to SVN add

```
    <exec executable="svn">
        <arg value="add" />
        <arg value="-q" />
        <arg value="--force" />
        <arg value="${dir}/Transform*.java" />
    </exec>
```